# Cancancan ability for specific case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I use `cancancan` gem for role based authorization rules. I need to preform something like:

```
can :read, Post, Post.status = 1
```

This means that user can read post with status = 1. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions) it should be as simple as

```
can :read, Post, status: 1
```

You must use database columns for these conditions (i.e. make sure `status` is a column in the `posts` table).

If this is not the case or you need something more complex than a hash of conditions, you can look into [Defining Abilities with Blocks](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks)

Hope this helps.

Comment: uninitialized constant Post::Status. Status is column in posts table

Comment: Are you putting `Status` with a capital s? It should be all lowercase (i.e. `status`)

Comment: Wat? Can you please post the full line of code you're using?

Comment: status written with capital s is from error output.

Comment: controller: `authorize! :show, @post`
ability.rb: `can :read, Post, status = 1`

Comment: As the docs say, it's supposed to be a *hash* of conditions. So do `can :read, Post, status: 1` and *NOT* `can :read, Post, status = 1`

Comment: Sry i posteded code with mistake, i'm actually using code `can :read, Post, status: 1`

Comment: Status is reserved word? Because if i'm using `id` or another field (even in block), everything works fine. Also, debug showed that status exists in passed Post variable.

Comment: It isn't a reserved work. Not sure what is going with your code but if you can't figure it out, I would suggest posting a separate question. I've created a working sample app with what I described above and it works just fine. See it [here](https://github.com/bjedrocha/cancanoverflow)

Comment: I renamed column from `status` to `state` and everything working just fine, confused...

Comment: It's hard to say without taking a looking at the rest of your code. If this answer helped you, please accept and upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
can(:read, Post, status: 1)
```

Comment: uninitialized constant Post::Status, my post controller: `authorize! :show, @post`